# alfresco workflow task: oncreate listener set some fields to view them

Tags: deployment, workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

I'm trying to deploy a new workflow in alfresco 4.0.e but I have a problem.

I have a task and I need to show some text message in that task. The message is in the execution of that task. So I created an onCreate listener that call my java function just when the task is creating.

```
public class LeaveRequestResultCreateEvent implements TaskListener{

@Override
public void notify(DelegateTask arg0) {
}

}
```

when process reach this task it calls notify function and I have access to all execution variables inside arg0.can I say alfresco to show the messages of this variable in my form? (In somewhere like share-workflow-form-config.xml in alfresco share)

Comment: You can check some of the out of box Task listener classes to get idea about how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to show the message in a later step, for example, you could do something like

```
arg0.setVariable("mymessage", "This is the message");
```

and then expose 'mymessage' in your content model and in a form in a later step.